# Text Box value not changing based on the option button value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a price calculator using excel VBA. Based on the unit selection to metric or imperial I want to display the appropriate unit in the text box besides the value.

This is the code that I have tried but it is not working.

```
If cmButton.Value = True Then

    Cells(emptyRow, 5) = "Metric"
    TextBox1.Value = "cm"
    TextBox2.Value = "cm"
    TextBox3.Value = "cm"
    TextBox4.Value = "g"

End If
    
If inchButton.Value = True Then

    Cells(emptyRow, 5) = "Imperial"
    TextBox1.Value = "inch"
    TextBox2.Value = "inch"
    TextBox3.Value = "inch"
    TextBox4.Value = "oz"
    
End If
```

Comment: Where are the option buttons located and where is the code located?

Comment: How is this called?

Comment: One note, since this is an either or, an `ElseIf` instead of two distinct `If`s may be better.

Comment: Hi Scott. I am using a userform in Excel VBA. Which contains a few text box for user to enter values of lenght, widht, height and weight of their product. I have used two option buttons on the userform namely, "cmbutton" and "inchbutton". Based on this selection I have developed the formulas in the backend to calculate the price.  Once user selects one of this options and enter values I have two command buttons, namely Calculate and Clear. I wanted to attach an image of my userform while posting my question on this portal but this portal didnt allow me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the code to look more like this:-

```
Private Sub cmButton_Click()

Cells(emptyRow, 5) = "Metric"
TextBox1.Value = "cm"
TextBox2.Value = "cm"
TextBox3.Value = "cm"
TextBox4.Value = "g"

End Sub

Private Sub inchButton_Click()

Cells(emptyRow, 5) = "Imperial"
TextBox1.Value = "inch"
TextBox2.Value = "inch"
TextBox3.Value = "inch"
TextBox4.Value = "oz"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for replying. I am using userform in excel vba. But these are option buttons not command buttons. Will I be able to write this program for option buttons in the VBA code? I am fairly new to programming and vba so my questions might sound silly. Sorry for that